# Does it matter what language I use for normal GTK3 apps? Will a user notice the difference?

Tags: go, rust, gtk3

I want to make an application with GTK3.
This will be an application to manage files (copy, move, ...) but mostly some windows with settings. (normal tabs, checkbox, selects, inputs, ...)
I may also need some custom drawn widgets.

As a language I would like to use Go because it is fast an simple to use. I tried the gotk3 library and the example seem to work fine on my macbook.

But I'm a bit worried about performance. Because cgo is used to use the gtk libraries, will this make the application slow? Or is this still fast enough for normal applications.

An alternative would be to use Rust. gtk-rs seems better then gotk3 because using c libraries in Rust is easier.

(I have no experience with GTK, C, Rust)

Will gotk3 be fast enough for a good user experience?
Will I notice a difference between gotk3 / gtk-rs / gtk in plain C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will gotk3 be fast enough for a good user experience?

Yes. Unless you write a very specific program like for low latency trading, the language in which you write your app does not matter.

Just pick up the language you prefer: Go, Rust, C, Python, D, etc. they are all used in various GNOME application without trouble.

The thing that matters is the algorithm you use. If you use an O(n²) instead of an O(log n) algorithm for example, it will be bad in C, Rust and Go.